# Can not make an unordered list based on its category

Tags: mysql

Table is as below:

[image]

category_amenities table is as below:

[image]

I made this query:

```
`SELECT amenities.subcategory from amenities inner join category_amenities 
on amenities.category=category_amenities.name 
where amenities.category= 
(select distinct category_amenities.name from category_amenities 
inner join amenities on category_amenities.name = amenities.category where category_amenities.name = 'Parking');`
```

Then i got this output:

```
Facilities
   Street Parking
   Bus Parking
   Complimentary Parking
   Paid Parking
   Valet Parking
Parking
 Street Parking
 Bus Parking
 Complimentary Parking
 Paid Parking
 Valet Parking
```

Please tell me how can i get the output as below:

```
 Facilities
   Onsite restaurant

Parking
   Street Parking
   Bus Parking
   Complimentary Parking
   Paid Parking
   Valet Parking
```

i need correction on my query above.

Comment: share your another table structure..

Comment: @KMS i added category_amenities table now.